# Is there standard software for scheduling tasks?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

At work we are tasked with implementing a scheduling system. Our current requirements call for us to schedule 2 types of tasks:

- Tasks that will execute once at a specific time: "Send a bulk push notification to the following devices at 2014-01-28T10:35:08+00:00"
- Repeating tasks: "Every Monday at 9am UTC, send a summary email to the following people"

The tasks themselves will all be command-line applications + parameters that need to be executed.

Up until this point, we have implemented repeating tasks using `cron`, but this is not sufficient in the long term, since we want to be robust:

- We want jobs to be transactional – if a machine fails while a job is running the job should not be marked as complete.
- We want to be able to run more than one machine in a fleet, but each task should only be run once by one machine
- We want to be easily able to view the schedule and state of jobs (perhaps a web interface).
- We want to have a `CRUD` API for managing jobs.
- If we have a machine failure and a machine come backs up, it should be able to find overdue tasks and run them.

Is there an industry standard tool for implementing this? When we want to store data we use a database, when we want to queue items we use a queue – what's the equivalent for scheduling tasks?

Comment: One (crazy?) idea that I had was to use the Google Calendar API for storing / adding / viewing tasks, and using a second system to poll the calendar looking for tasks that are due for execution.

Comment: This is veering off topic for the site because it's asking to recommend tools. Having said that there are many approaches you could take, Windows scheduled tasks is one, if you're planning to write code there's things like the quartz library

Comment: I'm totally willing to write code, but before I write any code I wanted to check to see if I would be re-inventing the wheel. ("Weeks of programming can save you hours of planning.")

Can you recommend a better stack-exchange to ask on?

Comment: I believe Quartz.net is a good place to start (I've not used it myself). Unfortunatly as "Suggest a" questions tend to be opinion based they're not really part of the SE network http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: https://quartz-scheduler.org/ is the correct link. Quoting their blurb: ... Java ...  from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. ... simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; ... The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as support for JTA transactions and clustering.

Answer (score 0):

[ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) can solve all your mentioned requirements. **monitoring**, analytics and exception handling and API.
.Net, Php, Ruby libraries are available, also [REST-API](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/5/rest-api-v10) for all others.

**Disclaimer**: I was among people who made this tool. It is a freeware, not commercial purpose.